# Do all threads share a static array in Futures-Callable?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, share, callable

I get the number of threads using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), and then I write like:

**ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);**

Next, using a for loop and **new Callable**, a function is called **in which there is a static array that all threads can access** and set an integer to a position of this array.

Actually, I wonder that is this logical?
Because I get an error when I want to access a position of the array after all threads finish their job.

Comment: Can you show the code`Next, using a for loop and new Callable, a function is called in which there is a static array that all threads can access and set an integer to a position of this array.`?

Comment: And the error you got?

Comment: Actually, rather than an error, there is an inconsistency for the value of the array position. Because it is different from the value that I expect. More clearly, I store a ciphertext encrypted with AES
in this position, then when I try to decrypt it, it produces different characters, including  ?, [ etc. So, I think that after a thread accesses and stores the value, another thread also accesses and writes a different value, and hence, the value in the position cannot be decrypted. @NengLiu

Comment: I don't know how I can provide synchronization since threads can access the same array, even the same array position. Should I prevent other threads from accessing the position when a thread accesses a position? @NengLiu

Comment: Sadly, that's not thread safe.